# Convert into PostgreSQL Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is one function which has one query ,

Now I want to convert into dynamic query. I want one table name parameter so query return data from multiple tables.

please help me in this I am new in PostgreSQL , Thanks in Advance !

```
create or replace function GetEmployees() 
returns setof weather as 
'select * from weather;' 
language 'sql';
```

Comment: You should always refer to the documentation. Trust me, it's a programmer's best friend.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: Anu, is this a follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937848/convert-sql-server-stored-procedure-into-postgresql-stored-procedure ?

Comment: If you want to pass the table name, you can't easily make this a "returns setof" function as the the passed table name might have a totally different structure than the `weather` table.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic PL/PgSQL. Use PL/PgSQL's [`EXECUTE .. USING` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and `format` function with the `%I` format-specifier.

```
create or replace function get_sometable(tablename regclass) 
returns setof whatever_type as 
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('select * from %I";', tablename);
END;
language 'plpgsql';
```

This will only work if all tablenames you might pass return compatible result types, as occurs with partitioning. Otherwise you'll have to return `SETOF RECORD` and then pass the table layout in the function invocation. See the documentation for a discussion of `RECORD` and `SETOF RECORD`.

Look into `RETURNS TABLE` as another convenient alternative for when the table types aren't compatible but you can still return a compatible subset via a suitable `SELECT` list.

If you're doing table partitioning, you should really do it [as the PostgreSQL documentation on table partitioning advises](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html), using table inheritance and triggers.

(Elaborating on [Convert SQL Server stored procedure into PostgreSQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937848/convert-sql-server-stored-procedure-into-postgresql-stored-procedure))