# Return Table using Dynamic SQL Query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my function in which I execute one dynamic query but I got result of this query in one single column and all values are in comma separated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_weather(city text)
RETURNS weather AS $$
DECLARE
rec RECORD;
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM weather WHERE city = ''' || city || '''' INTO rec;
RETURN rec;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result of above function :

```
"("San Francisco",46,50,0.25,1994-11-27)"
```

Required output :

[image]

Please help me in this, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please link back to prior related questions when you write a follow-up. It helps give the reader context about what you're taking about. In this case you really should've included *how you ran the function* and your exact PostgreSQL version.

Comment: thx.. anu ..g8 question...req solution found here

Answer (score 5):

You have to use SELECT FROM

```
SELECT * FROM get_weather('Prague');

postgres=# SELECT * FROM weather ;
  city  │ lo │ hi │     d      
────────┼────┼────┼────────────
 San Fr │ 46 │ 50 │ 2013-06-06
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM get_weather('San Fr');
  city  │ lo │ hi │     d      
────────┼────┼────┼────────────
 San Fr │ 46 │ 50 │ 2013-06-06
(1 row)

postgres=# \sf get_weather 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_weather(city text)
 RETURNS weather
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
rec RECORD;
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM weather WHERE city = $1' INTO rec USING sity;
RETURN rec;
END;
$function$
```

There are some possible optimization in your example

- Use RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
- don't use dynamic query ever - use RETURN QUERY
- use SQL language instead PL/pgSQL for one row functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_weather(city text)
RETURNS weather AS $$
SELECT * FROM weather WHERE city = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Attention: newer build dynamic query like you do! This is exemplary example of SQL injection problem.

Use instead

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM weather WHERE city = ' || quote_literal(city) INTO rec;
```

or better

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM weather WHERE city = $1'  INTO rec USING city;
```

Comment: thanks, but still this return comma separated values. please help in this, I am new in postgresql.

Comment: Some rather important context that @Anu left out is in this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16940583/398670 . You'll notice that there I used the format function's `%I` format-specifier for identifier substitution and mentioned `EXECUTE ... USING`.

Comment: @Anu what is your code on client side? Maybe is a problem there.

Comment: ok , thanks I got solution , need to just select *from function()